# Ubuntu Tweak crashes on launch Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: python, 13.04, ubuntu-tweak

When I start Ubuntu Tweak from Dash, System settings or Terminal, it immediatly crashes.

I get this error code from the Terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-tweak", line 124, in <module>
    from ubuntutweak.main import UbuntuTweakWindow
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/main.py", line 33, in <module>  
    from ubuntutweak.apps import AppsPage  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/apps/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>  
    from ubuntutweak.policykit.dbusproxy import proxy
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/policykit/dbusproxy.py", line 22, in <module>  
    from IN import INT_MAX  
ImportError: cannot import name INT_MAX
```

Any way to fix it, seems like an easy import fix?

Comment: I have exactly the same error.

Comment: open terminal and type > ubuntu-tweak --version ? update the output in your question

Comment: @XxxXxx ubuntu-tweak 0.8.2

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu Tweak 0.8.4, Now Compatible With Ubuntu 13.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
or
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

[Help Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/download-ubuntu-tweak-084-now.html)